# Not getting the desired output for a C# program to calculate and display simple and compound interest

Tags: c#, .net

I entered the C#c code into visual studio for the following program calculate and display simple and compound interest for the entered  principal amount,time and rate of interest but the output is coming as invaild but i need the output as a number.

Console output:

```
Enter the amount:
20000
Enter the rate:
5 
Enter the time:
10
1.Si
2.Ci
 Select the option
1
Invaild
```

```
using System;
class interest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double p, t, r, si, ci;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount:");
        p = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the rate:");
        r = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the time:");
        t = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("1.Si\n2.Ci\n Select the option");
        string ch=Console.ReadLine();
        if (ch == "Si")
        {
            si = (p * r * t) / 100;
            Console.WriteLine("Simple Interest=" + si);
        }
        else if (ch == "Ci")
        {
            ci = p * Math.Pow(1 + (r / 100), t) - p;
            Console.WriteLine("Compund Interest=" + ci);
        }
        else 
            Console.WriteLine("Invaild");
        
    }
    
}
```

I tried many methods such as changing the method and formula but no matter what i try,I am getting output as invalid for both simple and compound interest.I am supposed to get the following as shown in the image .[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBa3s.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your example run shows that you entered `1`, but you are testing `ch == "Si"`. Change it to `ch == "1"` and in the second test: `ch == "2"` or use a more flexible solution with a switch statement:

```cs
switch ch.ToLower()
{
    case "1" or "si":
        si = (p * r * t) / 100;
        Console.WriteLine("Simple Interest=" + si);
        break;
    case "2" or "ci":
        ci = p * Math.Pow(1 + (r / 100), t) - p;
        Console.WriteLine("Compund Interest=" + ci);
        break;
    defualt:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        break;
}
```

This allows you to either enter the option number or the option text by ignoring the letter case.